# Can Spring MVC's REST framework accept query strings rather than PathVariables?

Tags: spring-mvc, query-string, spring-3, path-variables

In all the tutorials and articles I have read regarding Spring 3's RESTful additions to Spring MVC, I have only ever seen one way for the use to pass in query data, via a `@PathVariable`, [like so](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/shops/{name}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name) {
    ...
}
```

which would respond to something like `http://www.example.com/myservlet/shops/{name}`, which could evaluate to `http://www.example.com/myservlet/shops/thebestshoparound`.

My question is this: Is it possible to set up a RESTful interface that takes requests based on classic query strings, e.g. `http://www.example.com/myservlet/shops?name=thebestshoparound`, instead of `PathVariables`?

This seems like a really simple question, but I can't find it anywhere online.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, use the annotation [`@RequestParam`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestparam), here is an example:

```
public @ResponseBody Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String name, @RequestParam(value="query", required=false) String query) {
    // do stuff
}
```